# AS3 - minor platformer class binding error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, error-handling, flash-cs5

There's a small problem with my code. I want to link all three classes to make a simple platformer. Here is the code:

Array Class:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.*;
public dynamic class setupStage extends Thiny
{
    var mapWid = 24;
    var mapHei = 40;
    var tileSide = 10;
    var totalTiles = mapWid * mapHei;
    var cell:tile=new tile();

    var firstStage:Array=[
      /*1*/[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
      /*2*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]
      /*3*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]
      /*4*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]
      /*5*/[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]
      /*6*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
      /*7*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
      /*8*/[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
      /*9*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*10*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*11*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]
     /*12*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*13*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*14*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
     /*15*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*16*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*17*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]
     /*18*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*19*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*20*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*21*/[1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*22*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*23*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*24*/[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*25*/[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*26*/[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*27*/[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*28*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
     /*29*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*30*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*31*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*32*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*33*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*34*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
     /*35*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*36*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*37*/[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*38*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*39*/[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     /*40*/[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
      ];
    function setupStage()
    {
        trace("access granted");
    }
    function drawMap():void
    {
        for (var i:int=0; i<mapWid; i++)
        {
            for (var u:int=0; u<mapHei; u++)
            {
                cell.gotoAndStop(firstStage[i][u]+1);
                cell.x = tileSide * i;
                cell.y = tileSide * u;
                with (stage)
                {
                    stage.addChild(cell);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Movement Class:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.sampler.StackFrame;

public dynamic class JAJEBIE extends Thiny{
var granica:setupStage = new setupStage();
var thinX = 0;
var thinY = 0;
var acc = 6;
var thin:thiny1 = new thiny1();
var przycisk:Object = {};

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,Move);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,Halt);
//with (thin){addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Opadanie);}

function wrzut():void
{
    addChild(thin);
    thin.x = 200;
    thin.y = 390;

}
function Move(k:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    przycisk[k.keyCode] = true;
    if (przycisk[Keyboard.LEFT] && granica.firstStage[thinX][thinY] == 0 && granica.firstStage[thinX - 1][thinY] == 0)
    {
        thin.x = thin.x - 10;
    }
    if (przycisk[Keyboard.RIGHT] && granica.firstStage[thinX][thinY] == 0 &&     granica.firstStage[thinX - 1][thinY] == 0)
    {
        thin.x = thin.x + 10;
    }
    if (przycisk[Keyboard.SPACE])
    {
        acc = 3;
        thin.y = thin.y + 30;
    }
}
//function Opadanie(Event);
//{
//thin.y = thin.y - 30;
//}
function Halt(k:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    przycisk[k.keyCode] = false;
}

}

}
```

The main fla file:

```
stop();
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.sampler.StackFrame;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,initialize);

function initialize(main_event:Event):void{
        with(setupStage){drawMap();};
        with(JAJEBIE){wrzut();};
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,initialize);
}
```

We tried many things, but compiler kept throwing up errors, even after we managed to delete all code problems, main class seem to not *want* to patch everything up.
Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: which lines of code are those referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an **instance** of each classes `JAJEBIE` and `setupStage`, so that you will have a specimen of your platformer level and player. Your code says that `JAJEBIE` is a static class, as it does not have a constructor, so you are right about addressing it via class name - unless error 5000 is thrown against `JAJEBIE`, in that case your code is PLAIN WRONG.

```
var jajebie:JAJEBIE;
function initialize(main_event:Event):void{
    jajebie=new JAJEBIE();
    addChild(jajebie);
    addChild(jajebie.granica);
    // while neither is added to stage, they 
    // cannot reach the stage! You have to point them to actual stage.
    jajebie.granica.drawMap(); // now, as we have stage access, draw the map
    jajebie.wrzut();
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,initialize);
}
```

Also, you have but one `cell` instance across `setupStage`, and you are repeatedly attempting to set its coordinates and put to stage. This approach is wrong, as you will end up with a single instance of `cell` on screen, it'll be bottom right one. Fix this by re-instantiating your `cell` within the inner cycle.

function drawMap():void
    {
        for (var i:int=0; i

And finally, you need to learn to read and interpret the error messages yourself, so that you can understand what does Flash want you to tell. Say, error 5000 means you have to extend a given class (most likely `MovieClip`) for either of your classes, which might force you to rework most of your code right away.